# Determine number of orders in a given status on a given day from changelog table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a MySQL version 8.x database. Here's some sample data from the changelog table:

```
|client_id | order_id | status_changed_from | status_changed_to | status_changed_date |
+----------+----------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|  1004023 |   220840 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-01-10 11:59:09 |
|  1004023 |   220840 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-01-31 12:23:28 |
|  1004023 |   221080 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-01-11 02:34:32 |
|  1004023 |   221080 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-02-11 02:34:32 |
|  1374019 |   221665 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-01-18 18:23:20 |
|  1374019 |   221665 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-02-19 22:12:03 |
|  1004023 |   221971 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-01-24 19:20:12 |
|  1004023 |   221971 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-02-20 12:19:43 |
|  1374019 |   230924 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-03-03 00:20:32 |
|  1374019 |   230924 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-03-14 21:53:57 |
|  1374019 |   234361 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-03-05 10:57:43 |
|  1374019 |   234361 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-03-15 18:29:03 |
|  1497671 |   238360 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-03-09 06:57:53 |
|  1497671 |   238360 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-03-20 11:17:42 |
|  1374019 |   266924 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-03-10 17:05:34 |
|  1374019 |   266924 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-03-25 22:05:39 |
|  1497671 |   274617 | Open                | In Progress       | 2015-03-13 17:12:15 |
|  1497671 |   274617 | In Progress         | Done              | 2015-03-26 16:40:02 |
```

Given this data, I am trying to determine the number of "In Progress" orders for a given client on a given day. For example, number of orders in progress on 2015-01-25:

```
| on_date    | orders_in_progress |
+------------+--------------------+
| 2015-01-25 | 4                  |
```

Or, number of order in progress on 2015-01-25 for client 1004023:

```
| on_date    | client_id   | orders_in_progress |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2015-01-25 | 1004023     | 3                  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want the last status date before a given date for either all or a given client.  Here is the idea:

```
select cl.client_id, '2015-01-25' as on_date, count(*)
from changelog cl
where cl.status_changed_date = (select max(cl2.status_changed_date)
                                from changelog cl2
                                where cl2.client_id = cl.client_id and
                                      cl2.status_changed_date <= '2015-01-25'
                               ) and
      cl.status_changed_to = 'In Progress'
group by cl.client_id;
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select cl.client_id, '2015-01-25', count(*)
from (select cl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by  status_changed_date desc) as seqnum
      from changelog cl
      where status_changed_date <= '2015-01-25'
     ) cl
where seqnum = 1
group by cl.client_id;
```

In either of these queries, you can filter down to one particular client, if you prefer.